# Wordpress open accordion code snippet. Request failed with status code 418 on dreamhost

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, code-snippets, mod-security

I am very new to javascript and php.

I am trying to write script in the Code Snippets plugin for a wordpress site to make anchor links to accordions open the accordion.

For example, the URL https://challengingbehavior.org/pyramid-model/overview/resources/#generalResources when clicked, should open the page, then scroll down to and open the accordion 'General Resources' with ID #generalResources.

Here is the code I created

```
function add_this_script_footer(){ ?>

<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
var hash = window.location.hash;
if(hash){
var element = $(hash);
if(element.length){
element.trigger('click');
}
}
});

</script>

<?php }

add_action('wp_footer', 'add_this_script_footer'); ?>
```

When I try to activate the snippet, it gives me the error "Could not create snippet. Request failed with status code 418."

[screenshot of code with error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IuvJ7.png)

I found this online... https://wordpress.org/support/topic/could-not-create-snippet-request-failed-with-status-code-418/
But not knowing enough about code, I don't know if this is my problem or something else.

If it matters...Dreamhost, Wordpress 6.4.2, PHP 8.3.

Any help would be appreciated.

Update:
Here is the code I put in the functions.php file instead. I am getting syntax errors and it causes an critical error on the site.

```
//anchor link open accordion

function anchor_open_accordion() { 

    $(document).ready(function() {
        var hash = window.location.hash;
        if (hash){
            var element = $(hash);
            if (element.length){
                element.trigger('click');
            }
        }
    });
}

add_action('wp_footer', 'anchor_open_accordion');
```

[Screenshot with error lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L2ngO.png)

Can someone tell me what change I need to make to my code to get it to work?

Comment: [418](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/418)? Really? At any rate, read this. https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/215947927-Enabling-the-Web-Application-Firewall#:~:text=DreamHost%20uses%20the%20HTTP%20response,a%20request%20to%20your%20website.

Comment: Their firewall appears to be blocking requests where the payload is "code", for security reasons, most likely in an attempt to prevent XSS attacks in a very "global" manner. That's a problem one would not have to deal with, if the code was properly placed in a file (like the functions.php of the theme - should be using a child theme then though, instead of overwriting that of a 3rd-party theme), instead of inserted via such a "code snippet" plugin.

Comment: I can not rule out ModSecurity / OWASP CRS blocking this upload over security concerns. Yet HTTP status code 418 (I'm a teapot) is not a status code that ModSecurity or CRS uses. So either this is a custom rule set / configuration by the hoster or it's something far away from ModSecurity or CRS. -- CRS dev on duty

Comment: Thank you for this info. I do have a child theme. I will try putting the code in the functions.php and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: See updated post for new code on the functions.php file. I am now getting syntax errors and it breaks the site. If I remove the code, the site works again.